# xDjango Inner Join tables with queryset

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to INNER join 2 tables: `Comments` and `Auth`. So I store `userid` in `Comments` table and I need to pair it with the `Auth`.

I did with `.raw()`, but I don't want to do with the `raw()`, I have tried also other like `get_objects_or_404` but that does not work either because of multiple queries.

Here is my query, works as excepted.

```
SELECT * FROM index_comment INNER JOIN auth_user WHERE index_comment.userid=auth_user.id
```

And here is my Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
content = models.TextField()
userid = models.IntegerField()
published = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
postid = models.IntegerField()
```

Views.py

```
def readPost(request, postName):
content = get_object_or_404(Post, link=postName)
kategori = get_object_or_404(Category, id=content.category_id)
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=content.username_id)  


if request.method == "POST":
    form = sendComment(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        formContent = strip_tags(request.POST["content"])
        newComment = Comment()
        newComment.content = formContent
        newComment.postid = content.id
        newComment.save()
        return redirect('post',content.link)


else:
    form = sendComment
    args = {
        "content": content,
        "kategori": kategori,
        "user":user,
        "commentForm": form,

    }

# return HttpResponse("cat.id")
    return render(request, "theme/single.html", args)
```

And here is the forms.py

```
class sendComment(forms.Form):
content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
```

So I need to pair `userid` from `Comments` table to `Auth` id, and then get the `username`.

Comment: So, where is your code that you are having an issue with?

Comment: I need to do same query with django function instead of raw(). And the issue is i can't pair both tables and there fore i can't get users username

Comment: But what have you tried? We can't write the query for you. Do you have your django code that isn't working?

Comment: You  are making this harder than it is.  Assuming that in your model you defined the userid column in index_comment as a foreign key pointing at auth_user.id.  Django does this for you automatically.

Comment: I have a comment section which fills userid when user is submittin comment post. So it's not foreignkey it is an integerfield. How do we do exatly? i didn't get it. Sorry im too new on django. I've added comment model

Comment: *Why* is it an IntegerField and not a ForeignKey?

Comment: Because i really don't know how to do with the foreign key

Comment: Well you should ask about that then, not about a completely different subject.

Comment: Well can you at least give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting up your models properly with a foreign key relationship ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)) from index_comment.userid to auth_user.id, Django will handle the join for you and make the columns of the joined table(auth_user) available through the primary model (index_comment).

Something like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    postid = models.IntegerField()
```

will tie the userid in your comment table to the user table of django's built auth functionality.  the name fields will be available to Comment like

> comment.userid.username

Comment: Did not register the userid when user send post from a comment form.

Comment: Are you using the django auth system, or a "roll your own"?  Is the user (auth) model imported properly and available to the comment?  Is the session working properly?  Is the user logged in?  You have a lot of reading to do in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/).

Comment: Yes im using the django's default auth system  not mine, and the rest is working like user.is_authenicated and so on.  Sessions is working and im using django 2.0 which could make a sense, don't know exactly.

Comment: verify that your comment entry form is sending the user to your store comment view and that your view is sending that user info to the db

Comment: Edited the post, can you please look at my views.py and forms.py.

Comment: You are still not defining the user field in your comment model as a foreign key.  Have you gone through the Django tutorial where it teaches how to utilize the django ORM interface?  You are using an incorrect field name when you try to populate the user.  You do not load the user into your comment object before saving.